# powershell - export-csv from foreach array result

Tags: powershell

I want to take the rows/results from the following two array searches and export to a csv, but I cannot see how to process the output to a file.

```
$inputfile = import-csv 'C:\Users\Desktop\working\8a.csv'

$OutAll1 = @()

foreach($row in $inputfile)
{

if($row.Parameter -contains "Type of file server")
{

echo "Hooray for Type of File Server"
$OutList = New-Object System.Object
$OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Parameter" -Value $line."Type of file server"
$OutAll1 += $OutList

}

if($row.Parameter -contains "File server")
{

echo "File Server"
$OutList = New-Object System.Object
$OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Parameter" -Value $line."Type of file server"        
$OutAll1 += $OutList
}
```

Here is were I fail to get output for my array :

```
Export-Csv 'c:\users\desktop\working\out.csv'
```

Or if I make the array a variable :

```
$data = $outall1 = @()
foreach($row in $data) {export-csv 'c:\users\desktop\working\out.csv'}
```

My goal is to take the result from the first and second search term and put in a csv, keeping the original column names (which are: "Component,Server,Parameter,Value")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have copied the row object first e.g. `$OutList = $row.PSObject.Copy()` (this is a *shallow copy* suitable for CSV processing).

However, it's easier to use pipelining and modify the row variable `$_` directly:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Desktop\working\8a.csv' | ForEach {
    if ($_.Parameter -match 'Type of file server') {
        Write-Information 'Hooray for Type of File Server'
        $_.Parameter = 'foo'
    } elseif ($_.Parameter -match 'File server') {
        $_.Parameter = 'bar'
    }
    # now output the modified row so that ForEach collects it in $csv
    $_
}
```

If no further processing is needed, you can export to another CSV directly without the `$csv` variable:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Desktop\working\8a.csv' | ForEach {
    ......................
    $_
} | Export-Csv 'c:\users\desktop\working\out.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Notes:

- `-contains` operator is for arrays; for strings use `-match` (also regex) or `-like` (use wildcards)
- Pipelining collects all output, including `echo`, so for the auxiliary messages use
  `Write-Information` or `Write-Host` and other `Write-` cmdlets except `Write-Output`.
- `+=` in case of arrays **recreates the entire array**: it copies the old contents into a new array along with the new element. It's arguably the worst possible method to populate a large array in PowerShell. Use `+=` only if it's a one-time operation not inside a loop, or the array is small and the time doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I appreciate the site letting me post. Here are the couple main parts that solved it.
1. I need to add additional "Add-member noteproperty" to get parts of the row I wanted.
2. I was correct in trying to "$varible | export-csv"; however I was unsuccessful before I posted and didn't see why. Here is the final working code:

```
$inputfile = import-csv 'C:\Users\Desktop\working\8a.csv' 


$OutAll1 = @()


foreach($row in $inputfile){

if($row.Parameter -like "Type of file server"){

    echo "Hooray for Type of File Server"
    $OutList = New-Object System.Object
    $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Component" -Value $row.Component
    $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Server" -Value $row.Server
    $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Parameter" -Value $row.Parameter
    $OutAll1 += $OutList

}

if($row.Parameter -contains "File server"){

   echo "File Server"
   $OutList = New-Object System.Object
   $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Component" -Value $row.Component
   $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Server" -Value $row.Server
   $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "Parameter" -Value $row.Parameter       
   $OutAll1 += $OutList
   }

$Outall1 | Export-csv 'c:\out.csv'
```

I always was mistakingly using $row and $line in the array.